# How to insert Python Variables into HTML?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5

[image]My intention is to set a QLabel Text, bypassing a python variable value in HTML.

For Example, I want to Display a QLabel with text as  **"File, Accounts, Inventory, Manufacture, PayRoll, Others "**, Where **"F, A, I, M, P, O "** is in Red Colour with an underline and remaining strings is in Black Colour. I Initialise string **"F"** in  variable "lbl_text". Now, I want to pass that variable value into an HTML tag? How to get it?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QLabel)      

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):                                        
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.lbl_others = QLabel()
        lbl_text = "F"                     # ********* Variable  ******************
        self.lbl_others.setText('<font color="red"><u>{lbl_text}!</u></font><font color="black">ile</font>')

        self.lay.addWidget(self.lbl_others)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()                                           
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want use some form of placeholder in a template that will always be substituted dynamically? Can you try to clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: create Multiple Qlabels with set text  as 1) HTML format, 2) Python  Format, 3) Java Format. In Wich first letter of  HTML, Python,Java ( "H","P","J") are in red colour with an underline and all other remaining strings in black color @musicamante

Comment: so My intention to assign "HTML","Python","Java" to some variables and replace it in HTML Phrase @musicamante

Comment: Sorry but your comments are still a bit obscure. Are you looking for a function specific for QLabel that substitutes a "variable", or what? You do know how string formatting works, don't you?

Comment: Image Added. I want to create this type of labels through loops. @musicamante

Comment: Again, do you know how to use and what `str.format()` and f-strings are? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html Just use a template: `template = '<font color="red"><u>{}!</u></font>{}'` `for value in 'HTML', 'Python, 'Java':` `label = QLabel(template.format(value[0], value[1:]))` or `for value in 'HTML', 'Python, 'Java':` `label = QLabel(f'<font color="red"><u>{value[0]}</u></font>{value[1:]}')`.